# Caliburn.Micro in .NET 3.5 project

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, caliburn.micro

I would like to use Caliburn.Micro framework in project based on .NET framework 3.5.

I can not add Caliburn.Micro to my project viac nuget because the latest version support in my opinion only .NET 4.0 a .NET 4.5.

```
Installing 'Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2'.
Successfully installed 'Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2'.
Adding 'Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2' to QSelfie.
Uninstalling 'Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'Caliburn.Micro 1.5.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

I tried instal Caliburn.Micro 1.0.0 via nuget console but I got error.

```
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Caliburn.Micro 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain any assembly r
eferences or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Caliburn.Micro -Version 1.0.0
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Is there any Caliburn.Micro support .NET 3.5 projects?

Answer (score 1):

There were some old instructions about building a version of `Caliburn.Micro` against .NET 3.5 which might be of use: https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/discussions/247880

It might be quicker to scour some of the [forks](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network?size=2147483647) on `Codeplex`, it seems like a couple of users maintain versions built against .NET 3.5:

https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/StephenWard1984/CaliburnMicro35

would seem to be the most up to date.

Comment: I clone this fork https://git01.codeplex.com/forks/stephenward1984/caliburnmicro35 but it seem it is .NET 4.0 :(